# Atom editor not showing suggestions or importing node modules

Tags: node.js, reactjs, visual-studio-code, import, atom-editor

I have been using VSCode for several years, but I recently decided to move to Atom. VSCode has built-in a ton of features, including a very well-built auto-suggestion system. Whenever I started typing something in VSCode, I got a suggestion. Unfortunately, this is not the case in Atom.

I have tried autocomplete-modules, autocomplete-paths, and atom-ternjs, but with no luck. What I want is a proper, working autosuggestion system that also imports on select.

I work with [Material-UI](https://mui.com/) and [Material Design Icons](https://materialdesignicons.com/) and both of these were automatically suggested and imported in VSCode. I mostly write JavaScript for React.js and Node.js for the backend.

Answer (score 0):

you have to install for language https://github.com/atom/autocomplete-plus/wiki/Autocomplete-Providers

read this https://atom.io/packages/autocomplete-plus

Comment: I had already installed the required JavaScript provider (atom-ternjs) and I now installed the TypeScript as well, but I still do not get suggestions. I played around with the settings a bit, but still no luck. Any thoughts?

Comment: have you downloaded autocomplete-plus ? may be work after installation. play with it again

Comment: Looks like I will be using VSCodium. The reason I moved to Atom was that VSCode was not fully open source and I HATE TRACKING! VSCodium is to VSCode what Chromium is to Chrome.

Comment: I agree with you mate. the kite can be a better alternative to auto-code completion.
https://www.kite.com/integrations/atom-editor/

try this